# cell of tableview is not nil on initialize in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am beginner of swift programing and new to ios as well . i am trying to to make an table view but the condition of    if(cell == nil ) but the cell is never nil and is not going into condition here is my code .

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //cell content declaration

        var rightlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(200, 10, 200, 21))
        var mainTextLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 21))
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        var cell : UITableViewCell!

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailsCell") as? UITableViewCell


    //cell content declaration END




if(cell == nil)
{

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let test: AnyObject? = myData?.objectForKey("\(indexPath.row + 1)")
    let hrvalue : AnyObject? = test?.objectForKey("name")
    let subtitle : NSNumber? = test?.objectForKey("distance") as? NSNumber
    let icon : String = test?.objectForKey("icon") as String



    //CUSTOM LABEL START FROM HERE

        mainTextLabel.text = hrvalue as? String
        rightlabel.text = "\(subtitle as Float ) k.m. away from here."

        mainTextLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)
        rightlabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)

        let image = UIImage(named: icon)
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)

        mainTextLabel.tag = 4
        rightlabel.tag = 50
        imageView.tag = 100

        cell.contentView.addSubview(mainTextLabel)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(rightlabel)
        cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)



    //CUSTOM LABEL END

}
   if(cell != nil)
   {
println("outside")

    //FATCHING TAG & RETURN CELL

        mainTextLabel = cell.viewWithTag(4) as UILabel
        rightlabel = cell.viewWithTag(50) as UILabel
        imageView = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UIImageView
        }
        return cell

    // FATCHING TAG & RETURN CELL END


    }
```

Comment: Are you using prototype cells in a storyboard or otherwise registered a class/nib against the reuse identifier?  If so then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will never return nil.  Your code inside the `if cell==nil` doesn't make sense either - In the traditional approach where a cell class or nib isn't registered you don't call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:indexPath:` in this case, you actually need to allocate a new cell

Comment: yes i am using prototype cell in storyBoard

Comment: i change my code and remove cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailsCell") as? UITableViewCell and added it to the if cell != nil , 
 and now i get nil value but it is not going inside the if condition

Comment: No, if you are using prototype cells you just call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and you never get nil - so all of the adding text fields etc should be done through Interface Builder in the prototype cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cell can never be nil as you are initiating cell right at the start in the `// cell content declaration` area already. So now you have an instance of cell. Hence it can't be nil further down. Further down you are introducing code checking if (cell == nil). As a result that code never gets invoked.

Or in other words you are trying to re-instantiate cell redundantly. Get rid of the first:

`cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailsCell") as? UITableViewCell`

and you code down below will get called.

Also, the second condition further down (cell != nil) will always evaluate to YES as at this point in time you will have created an instance of cell one way or another. So you may want to get rid of that test as well.

Comment: i removed this line `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("detailsCell") as? UITableViewCell ` from `  // cell content declaration ` and i get nil value yet the code under the if (cell == nil) not work

Comment: So, first of all it seems your original questions got answered. I'd appreciate it if you'd tag my answer as correct ;-) Secondly, make sure you are doing things in the right order.
1.) get a cell (which now works)
2.) create subviews and add them to the cell
3.) assign values to those views

The hierarchy is like this:
Cell contains SubViews, Subviews have properties.
I think you are messing up the order.